# IIS load balancing for asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, iis, load-balancing

We have developed an ASP.NET application that uses a backend SQL Server database (dedicated server).
Application will be used by 30-40 users (but not more)

To prevent performance issues we are planning to load balance these application by installing 2 webservers (Windows Server 2012 / ISS 8.0).

QUESTION: Will load balancing significantly improve performance, taking in consideration the relatively low number of user requests (30-40 users in total) ?

Comment: The answer to almost every performance question is the same...benchmark.  That's the only way to know where your bottlenecks are.

Comment: Without seeing the code for your app it's tough to tell, but it seems odd to want to load balance for 30-40 users. I'm used to load balancing for tens of thousands through hundreds of thousands of users...

Comment: Code has some pages which require intense cpu resources

Answer (score 0):

Generally one server can handle around more than 2000 request at a time which depends on CPU core. Definitely load balancing improves the performance of application as it divided the traffic between two servers based on the routing request at LB.

Let me know if you require any more information.